# Dynamically creating variables, while doing map/apply on a dataframe in pandas to get key names for the values in Series object returned

Tags: variables, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas

I am writing code for a Naive Bayes model(I know there's a standard implementation in Sklearn, but I want to code it anyway) - For this I have say upwards of 30 features, against all of which I have the corresponding click & impression counts (Treat them as True/False flags)

What I need then, is to calculate

```
P(Click/F1, F2.. F30) = (P(Click)*P(F1/Click)*P(F2|click) ..*P(F30|Click))/(P(F1, F2...F30), and 
P(NoClick/F1, F2.. F30) = (P(NoClick)*P(F1/NoClick)*P(F2|Noclick) ..*P(F30|NOClick))/(P(F1, F2...F30)
```

Where I will disregard the denominator as it will affect both Click & Non click behaviour similarly.

Example, for two features, day_custom & is_tablet_phone, I have

```
is_tablet_phone click   impression
FALSE   375417  28291280
TRUE    17743   4220980


day_custom  click   impression
Fri 77592   7029703
Mon 43576   3773571
Sat 65950   5447976
Sun 66460   5031271
Thu 74329   6971541
Tue 55282   4575114
Wed 51555   4737712
```

**My approach to the Problem**  : Assuming I read the individual files in data frame, one after another, I want the abilty to calculate & store the corresponding Probablities back in a file, that I will then use for real time prediction of Probabilty to click vs no click.

One possible structure of "processed file" thus would be -:

Here's my entire code -:

In the full blown example, I am traversing the entire directory structure(of 30 txt files, one at a time, from the base path) - which is why I need the ability to create "names" at runtime.

```
for base_path in base_paths:
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_path):
        for file in files:
            file_paths.append(os.path.join(root, file))
```

**For reasons of tractability, follow from here**, by taking the 2 txt files as sample input

```
file_paths=['/home/ekta/Desktop/NB/day_custom.txt','/home/ekta/Desktop/NB/is_tablet_phone.txt']
flag=0
for filehandle in file_paths:
    feature_name=filehandle.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
    df= pd.read_csv(filehandle,skiprows=0, encoding='utf-8',sep='\t',index_col=False,dtype={feature_name: object,'click': int,'impression': int})
    df2=df[(df.impression-df.click>0) & (df.click >0)]
    if flag ==0:
        MySumC,MySumNC,Mydict=0,0,collections.defaultdict(dict)
        MySumC=sum(df2['click'])
        MySumNC=sum(df2['impression'])
        P_C=float(MySumC)/float(MySumC+MySumNC)
        P_NC=1-P_C
    for feature_value in df2[feature_name]:
        Mydict[feature_name+'_'+feature_value]={'P_'+feature_name+'_'+feature_value+'_C':(df2[df2[feature_name]==feature_value]['click']*float(P_C))/MySumC, \
                                              'P_'+feature_name+'_'+feature_value+'_NC':(df2[df2[feature_name]==feature_value]['impression']*float(P_NC))/MySumNC}

     flag=1 %Set the flag as "1" because we don't need to compute the MySumC,MySumNC, P_C & P_NC again
```

**Question :**
It looks like THIS loop is the killer here.Also, intutively, looping on a dataframe is a BAD practice. How can I rewrite this, perhaps using Map/Apply ?

```
for feature_value in df2[feature_name]:
    Mydict[feature_name+'_'+feature_value]={'P_'+feature_name+'_'+feature_value+'_C':(df2[df2[feature_name]==feature_value]['click']*float(P_C))/MySumC, \
                                                      'P_'+feature_name+'_'+feature_value+'_NC':(df2[df2[feature_name]==feature_value]['impression']*float(P_NC))/MySumNC}
```

**What I need in Mydict , which is a hash to store each feature name and each feature value in it**

```
{'day_custom_Mon':{'P_day_custom_Mon_C':.787,'P_day_custom_Mon_NC': 0.556},
        'day_custom_Tue':{'P_day_custom_Tue_C':0.887,'P_day_custom_Tue_NC': 0.156},
        'day_custom_Wed':{'P_day_custom_Tue_C':0.087,'P_day_custom_Tue_NC': 0.167}
        'day_custom_Thu':{'P_day_custom_Tue_C':0.947,'P_day_custom_Tue_NC': 0.196},
'is_tablet_phone_True':{'P_is_tablet_phone_True_C':.787,'P_is_tablet_phone_True_NC': 0.066},
'is_tablet_phone_False':{'P_is_tablet_phone_False_C':.787,'P_is_tablet_phone_False_NC': 0.077},
        .. and so on..
%PPS: I just made up those float numbers, but you get the point
```

**Also because I will later serialize this file & pass to Redis directly, for other systems to feed on it, in an cron-job manner, so I need to preserve some sort of Dynamic naming .**

**What I tried -:**

Since I am reading feature_name as

```
feature_name=filehandle.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]` # thereby abstracting & creating variables dynamically
def funct1(row):
    return row[feature_name]
def funct2(row):
    return row['click']
def funct3(row):
    return row['impression']
```

then..
`df2.apply(funct2,axis=1)df2.apply(funct,axis=1)*float(P_C))/MySumC, df2.apply(funct3,axis=1)*float(P_NC))/MySumNC`  Gives me both the values I need for a feature_value(say Mon, Tue, Wed, and so on..) for a feature_name (say,day_custom)
I also know that `df2.apply(funct1, axis=1)` contains part of mycustom "names"(ie feature values), how would I then build these names using map/apply ?

Ie. I will have the values, but how would I create the "key" `'P_'+feature_name+'_'+feature_value+'_C'` , since feature value post apply is returned as a series object.

Comment: could you please adjust formatting of what you tried so far? Noone can really read that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**itertuples() is what worked for me**(worked at lightspeed) - though It is still not using the map/apply approach that I so much wanted to see. Itertuples on a pandas dataframe returns the whole row, so I no longer have to do `df2[df2[feature_name]==feature_value]['click']` - be aware that this **matching by value is not only expensive**, **but also undesired**, since it may return a series, if there were duplicate rows. itertuples solves that problem were elegantly, though I need to then access the individual objects/columns by integer indexes , which means less re-usable code. I could abstract this, but It wont be like accessing by column names, the status-quo.

```
for row in df2.itertuples():
    Mydict[feature_name+'_'+str(row[1])]={'P_'+feature_name+'_'+str(row[1])+'_C':(row[2]*float(P_C))/MySumC, \
                                          'P_'+feature_name+'_'+str(row[1])+'_NC':(row[3]*float(P_NC))/MySumNC}
```

Note that  I am accesing each column in the row by row[1] , row[2] and like. For example, row has `(0, u'Fri', 77592, 7029703)`

Post this I get

```
dict(Mydict)
{'day_custom_Thu': {'P_day_custom_Thu_NC': 0.18345372640838162, 'P_day_custom_Thu_C': 0.0019559423132143377}, 'day_custom_Mon': {'P_day_custom_Mon_C': 0.0011466875948906617, 'P_day_custom_Mon_NC': 0.099300235316209587}, 'day_custom_Sat': {'P_day_custom_Sat_NC': 0.14336163246883712, 'P_day_custom_Sat_C': 0.0017354517827023852}, 'day_custom_Tue': {'P_day_custom_Tue_C': 0.001454726996987919, 'P_day_custom_Tue_NC': 0.1203925662982053}, 'day_custom_Sun': {'P_day_custom_Sun_NC': 0.13239618235343156, 'P_day_custom_Sun_C': 0.0017488722589598259}, 'is_tablet_phone_TRUE': {'P_is_tablet_phone_TRUE_NC': 0.11107365073163174, 'P_is_tablet_phone_TRUE_C': 0.00046690100046229593}, 'day_custom_Wed': {'P_day_custom_Wed_NC': 0.12467127727567069, 'P_day_custom_Wed_C': 0.0013566522616712882}, 'day_custom_Fri': {'P_day_custom_Fri_NC': 0.1849842396242351, 'P_day_custom_Fri_C': 0.0020418070466026303}, 'is_tablet_phone_FALSE': {'P_is_tablet_phone_FALSE_NC': 0.74447539516197614, 'P_is_tablet_phone_FALSE_C': 0.0098789704610580936}}
```

Answer (score 1):

check out the following recipe which does exactly what you want, only using data frame manipulations. I also simplified the actual frequency calculation a bit ;)

```
#set the feature name values as the index of 
df2.set_index(feature_name, inplace=True)

#This is what df2.set_index() looks like:
#                click  impression
#day_custom                       
#Fri              9917        3163
#Mon              2566        3818
#Sat              8725        7753
#Sun              6938        8642
#Thu              6136        2556
#Tue              5234        2356
#Wed              9463        9433

#rename the index of your data frame
df2.rename(index=lambda x:"%s_%s"%('day_custom', x), inplace=True)

#compute the total sum of your data frame entries
totsum = float(df2.values.sum())

#use apply to multiply every data frame element by the total sum
df2 = df2.applymap(lambda x:x/totsum)

#transpose the data frame to have the following shape
#day_custom  day_custom_Fri  day_custom_Mon  ...  
#click             0.102019        0.037468  ...   
#impression        0.087661        0.045886  ...
#
#
dftranspose = df2.T

# template kw for formatting
templatekw = {'click':"P_%s_C", 'impression':"P_%s_NC"}

# build a list of small data frames with correct index names P_%s_NC etc
dflist = [dftranspose[[col]].rename(lambda x:templatekw[x]%col) for col in dftranspose]

#use the concatenate function to produce a sparse dictionary
MyDict= pd.concat(dflist).to_dict()
```

Instead of assigning to `MyDict` at the end, you can use the `update`-method during the loop.

For understanding the comments below, see here my

## Original answer:

Try to use a `pivot_table`:

```
def clickfunc(x):
    return np.sum(x) * P_C / MySumC
def impressionfunc(x):
    return np.sum(x) * P_NC / MySumNC

newtable = df2.pivot_table(['click', 'impression'], 'feature_name', \
                aggfunc=[clickfunc, impressionfunc])

#transpose the table for the dictionary to have the right form
newtable = newtable.T

#to_dict functionality already gives the correct result
MyDict = newtable.to_dict()

#rename by copying
for feature_value, subdict in MyDict.items():
    word = feature_name +"_"+ feature_value
    copydict[word] = {'P_' + word + '_C':subdict['click'],\
                      'P_' + word + '_NC':subdict['impression'] }
```

This gives you the result you want in `copydict`

Comment: I have only unique values in the df2 (for a feature_name), will pivot help ? See also, day_custom & is_tablet_phone.txt files. If pivot will help, please also explain the intuition on WHY I need to pivot in this case(with no duplicate values) ?

Comment: as far as I see, your `feature_name` stays constant... The `pivot_table` groups the df2 into one group per `feature_value`, which is the intention of your for-loop, isn't it?

Comment: If there are only unique values, then grouping makes no sense, but your loop doesn't, either. Have you tried `reindex`?

Comment: I updated my post as you asked. Also I think there are some problems with the code .  word = feature_name +"_"+ feature_value - Feature_value is a tuple object, so we cant concat them. Also newtable = df2.pivot_table(['click', 'impression'], 'feature_name', \
                aggfunc=[clickfunc, impressionfunc]) returns the same things two times over - Perhaps you meant something else ? 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Naive_Bayes_NonOptimized.py", line 49, in <module>
    word = feature_name +"_"+ feature_value
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tuple' objects

Comment: items are tuples, indeed, which is why I unpack them via `feature_value, subdict in ...` Anyway, I see you have already figured a way you liked.

Comment: Gregor - +1 for making the time & effort. I have to admit that itertuples() struck me, omly when I saw the tuples in your code. I am not accepting, since I am still looking at a map/apply way(possibly) to solve this.

Comment: Hi, I think that an apply-command is not possible for your particular situation. I tried some renaming etc., but it all ends with iterating over the data frame once for generating your dictionary structure.

Comment: No, I had not. I need to,thanks for flagging- way more elegant.